# 1-standard deviation from median (for hist data)

Tags: python, python-2.7, standard-deviation

I have bins of known wide and size (measurement count within) and I'm trying to find the positions in R above and below the median associated with having gone out 34.15% (on both sides, so 68.3% like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) of my total histogram area. I don't care about the graph though.

**1st try**:

```
#hRd0s is an array of arrays, where the stuff inside of it are the bins
area = 0.
counter = 0 #used to count increments taken
increment = 0.
for i in range(len(hRd0s)): #sneaking suspicion this is where problem starts
    a = 0.001 * len(hRd0s[i])
    area += a
    increment += 0.001
    counter += 1
    if area <= half1sig: #i have half1sig defined above
        i +=1 #i figured this was how id move to next bin if half1sig wasnt satisfied
uppersteps = counter * 0.001
uppersigma = uppersteps + RmedhRd0s
print area
print uppersigma
```

The error it **was** giving me:

```
    if area <= half1sig:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Update 1: I am no longer getting this ValueError notification.**

**2nd try:**

```
area = 0.
counter = 0 #used to count increments taken
increment = 0.
while area < half1sig:
    for i in range(len(hRd0s)):
        a = 0.001 * len(hRd0s[i])
        area += a
        increment += 0.001
        counter += 1
        if area < half1sig:
            i +=1
uppersteps = counter * 0.001
uppersigma = uppersteps + RmedhRd0s
print area
print uppersigma
```

I thought this would work, but the issue now is that i need this to work on summing up area to the LEFT of the median only, whose position is RmedhRd0s. How can i work this into my loop? I will need to work on the left and right sides separately, i am trying to understand how to do this properly and efficiently though for one side.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `half1sig`; the problem is with `area`, in your code `area` is an array, because:

If `hRd0s` is an array of arrays, then `hRd0s[i]` will be an array. Therefore `a` will be an array because `a = 0.001 * hRd0s[i]`. Now when `a` is an array, `area` will be an array too because `area += a`. Therefore `if area <= half1sig` does not make sense, as the traceback of your error suggests: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.`

### After the update to the question:

The provided info are still limited. So my best guess is that since you are using a `while` statement, there is no longer a need for the for-loop. Change your code to the following (remove the for-loop and use the `counter` variable you already have instead of `i`) and see if it will get fixed:

```
area = 0.
counter = 0 #used to count increments taken
increment = 0.
while area < half1sig:
    a = 0.001 * len(hRd0s[counter])
    area += a
    increment += 0.001
    counter += 1
uppersteps = counter * 0.001
uppersigma = uppersteps + RmedhRd0s
print area
print uppersigma
```

But as I said, the info are still limited; for example I don't understand what the role of the `increment` variable is here...

Comment: Thanks @bbkglb, I fixed that and it got rid of that problem. Now my problem is in summing up all of those areas..

Comment: @TC What is the problem there? I can see that you are doing `i += 1` when `area <= half1sig`. Replace that `i += 1` with `continue` and see if that fixes your problem. Otherwise you would have to update your question and provide more info regarding your second issue.

Comment: I updated it to better reflect the issue. I do not know how to make the code properly go by increments (0.001) in radius, for radii only greater than RmedhRd0s, taking area measurements along the way of the increment*binsize and adding them up, and then knowing that if it has gone the binwidth length of the bin but the area does not equal half1sig? To move onto the next bin, hRd0s[i], and repeat. Does this clear that up?

Comment: @TC So by `len(hRd0s[i])` you are trying to get the length of the `i`th bin? If that's the case you are not doing it correctly.

Comment: I do not understand how that doesn't give me the length of it..? For example, if `hRd0s[0]` has 30 measurements in it, so 30 rows, i would get `len(hRd0s[0])=30`, right..? Also, the point of `increment` is that my data sets get so big that i do not always know spacings between radius values, or what they will be. So i want to make sure i'm going out a small enough radius to be most accurate. Actually.. I guess i don't want to do that.. I want to go out the next row in `hRd0s[0]`... How do i access that @bbkglb ?